# Install Windows Service using WIX

Tags: installation, wix

I have some troubles with WIX Services. My msi installer can create Service, but after creation installer can't start it. There is my code, which I use for Service.

```
<Component Id="borland_comp" Guid="{6F723B32-E95A-4545-87FD-0B5F7B114FCA}" DiskId="1">
        <File Id="server_ScktSrvr.exe" Name="ScktSrvr.exe"  KeyPath="yes"/>
        <ServiceInstall Id="BORLAND_Socket"
                            Name="Borland Socket Server"
                            DisplayName="Borland Socket Server"
                            Type="shareProcess"
                            Start="auto"
                            ErrorControl="normal"
                            Description="Borland Socket Server" />

        <ServiceControl Id="StartWixServiceInstaller"
                        Name="Borland Socket Server" Start="install" Wait="no" />

        <ServiceControl Id="StopWixServiceInstaller" Name="Borland Socket Server"
                        Stop="both" Wait="yes" Remove="uninstall"/>

      </Component>
```

Answer (score 3):

I would combine the two Service Control elements to become:

```
  <ServiceControl Id="scBSS" Name="Borland Socket Server" Stop="both" Start="install" Wait="yes" Remove="uninstall"/>
```

Although that probably isn't your problem.  Does the installer attempt to start it during the install?  Do you get an error message?  If you try to start it after the install do you get an error message?   Have you profiled / debug the service itself to make sure you aren't missing and dependencies or configuration data or throwing any exceptions in the code?

Comment: Yes, I get an "Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion". But I can install and run this service using CMD.

Comment: Try taking the ServiceControl element out and starting the service manually ( net start ) after the isntall has finishd. Does that work or does it fail?